# Popen chaining with command sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

On Windows I successfully run this:

```
cmd = ["gfortran", "test.f90", "-o", "test.exe", "&&", "test.exe"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(p.stdout.read())
```

On Ubuntu I change `cmd` to:

```
cmd = ["gfortran", "test.f90", "-o", "test", "&&", "./test"]
```

and get:

> gfortran: fatal error: no input files
>   compilation terminated.

I want to retain `cmd` as a list, instead making it a string.
How can I make this work?

Comment: It's impossible. cmd as a list **has different meaning** when shell is `True`. [_If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself._](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). Use `shlex.quote(cmd)` (`pipes.quote` in Python2).

Comment: Are you willing to consider using `shell=False` and using `subprocess` to call `test.exe` separately?

Comment: No, because I use interface provided by application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible. When `cmd` is a list, it has different meaning when shell is True. [Quoting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string,
>   and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to
>   the shell itself.

Use `' '.join(shlex.quote(arg) for arg in cmd)` (`pipes.quote` in Python2) when passing list of arguments to `Popen` with `shell=True` for expected behavior. Original list won't be mutated, string will be built before passing to function and garbage collected as soon as it's possible.

Comment: On my Python 3.5 `shlex.quote` expects string.

Comment: @vlad obviously, my bad, fixed now.

Comment: Not that simple, as that wont take care of correct paths. What if I have filename with spaces?

Comment: Ok, now I guess that's the best we can get. Thanks

Comment: Ugh, sorry about that, it's like 5th time I made that same mistake with shlex.quote in SO answer, my bad.

Comment: Just to add that it quotes `&&` too: `gfortran -o test test.f90 '&&' ./test`, which breaks chaining, so at least that should be handled by hand.

Comment: Yep, because that's what essentially is represented in shell by this command list. You mixed up two concepts, either you create a list of arguments and do not use `shell=True` to skip shell entirely or you want to use _shell capabilities_ (**&&** is shell capability, not argument to any of executables), and if that's the case there is no interpretation of list of commands whatsoever. You pass a string to shell, shell parses it itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116517/discussion-between-rogalski-and-vlad).

Answer (score 1):

This is what the docs state:

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself.

If you want to retain the arguments as a list, you can join them while calling `Popen`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(' '.join(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: `I want to retain cmd as a list, instead making it a string.` seems to imply that OP would like to pass as a list. Is that possible at all?

Comment: As the docs state: "If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself". So no. The `join()` also won't modify the original list at all, it will just be *passed* as a string.

Comment: The other answer clarified a bit better. The issue is with `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using `shell=True` to allow you to do `&&` on the command line. This is not strictly necessary if you are already using `subprocess` anyway:

```
cmd1 = ["gfortran", "test.f90", "-o", "test.exe"]
cmd2 = ["test.exe"]
if not subprocess.call(cmd1):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, ...)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    ...
```